# domready event and iframes

Tags: jquery, iframe, extjs, domready

If I do...

```
Ext.onReady(function(){alert('Ready');})
```

or...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){alert('Ready');})
```

...and if I have an iframe on the page I'm running this on, the functions don't run until after the iframe has loaded its content.

This is not how I thought these domready functions were supposed to work. I thought they specifically did not wait until things like images and iframes loaded.

Can someone enlighten me? Is there a domready approach I can use which does not wait for iframes?

Thanks

Comment: domeready means all of the elements HAVE been loaded, therefore it has to wait for them.

Comment: domready wait for the dom to be fully loaded, but it doesn't wait for all external resources to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set your **iframe src="" in markup**. And in your **document.ready** handler set **$iframe.attr('src', "http://....")**. This is what we usually do in our projects in the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is related to fouc problem that i faced while loading jquery tabs with considerable data load on each tabs.The tabs was rendering after the whole dom has been processed by the browser.My experience says that your jquery methods will trigger only when dom reading is complete.

See my situation [here](http://fundapass.blogspot.com/2012/06/v-behaviorurldefaultvmlo_22.html)